# Java time difference

Tags: java, php, datetime, timezone

Getting the timestamp from mysql it returns something like this "2014-03-19 12:00:43"  and in java I'm wanting to get the difference from the timestamp and the current time.

New to java and very unfamiliar, here is what I had in php though.... anything similar that would achieve the same thing

```
date_def
```

New to java and very unfamiliar, here is what I had in php though.... anything similar that would achieve the same thing

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$server = timesince($row['timestamp']);

function timesince($time){
    $seconds = strtotime($time) - time();
    $days = floor($seconds/ -86400);
    $seconds %= 86400;
```

New to java and very unfamiliar, here is what I had in php though.... anything similar that would achieve the 
New to java and very unfamiliar, here is what I had in php though.... anything similar that would achieve the same thing

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$server = timesince($row['timestamp']);
```

New to java and very unfamiliar, here is what I had in php though.... anything similar that would achieve the same thing

New to java and very unfamiliar, here is what I had in php though.... anything similar that would achieve the same thing

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$server = timesince($row['timestamp']);

function timesince($time){
    $seconds = strtotime($time) - time();
    $days = floor($seconds/ -86400);
    $seconds %= 86400;time();
    $days = floor($seconds/ -86400);
    $seconds %= 86400;

function timesince($time){
    $seconds = strtotime($time) - time();
    $days = floor($seconds/ -86400);
    $seconds %= 86400;
    $seconds = strtotime($time) - time();
    $days = floor($seconds/ -86400);
    $seconds %= 86400;ault_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

New to java and very unfamiliar, here is what I had in php though.... anything similar that would achieve the same thing

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$server = timesince($row['timestamp']);

function timesince($time){
    $seconds = strtotime($time) - time();
    $days = floor($seconds/ -86400);
    $seconds %= 86400;
    $minutes = floor($seconds / -60);
    $seconds %= 60;
    $seconds *= -1;

    if ($days > 360){
        return "Not voted here yet.";
    }

    if($days > 1){
        $days = $days." days, ";
    } elseif ($days == 1){
        $days = $days." day, ";
    } else {
        $days  = "";
    }
    if($hours > 1){
        $hours = $hours." hours, ";
    }elseif ($hours == 1){
        $hours = $hours." hour, ";
    } else {
        $hours  = "";
    }
    if($minutes > 1){
        $minutes = $minutes." minutes and ";
    }elseif ($minutes == 1){
        $minutes = $minutes." minute and ";
    }else {
        $minutes  = "";
    }
    if($seconds > 1){
        $seconds = $seconds." seconds";
    }elseif ($seconds == 1){
        $seconds = $seconds." second";
    }

    return $days.$hours.$minutes.$seconds." ago";
}
```

I don't see anything similar to strtotime in java, and don't want to use any additional libraries.

Also in the php script I have at the top

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

so it gets the right time difference with timezone accounted for.

Where to start with doing something similar in java though?

Comment: Am I right that you mean JavaScript, not Java?

Comment: You mean java or javascript? Because it does not make sens to say yeah I meant Java, when the question is do you mean javaScript not java? Confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this in Java (or PHP, for that matter). This is something to be done in MySQL, using its [date/time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(my_timestamp_col) AS seconds_ago ...
```

The first method returns the current time as a [unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (ie, seconds since epoch). The second method returns the `my_timestamp_col` time as a unix timestamp. Subtract the two, and you have how many seconds ago `my_timestamp_col` was.

**EDIT:** This gets more complicated when you factor in timezones, as Alexander points out. One option is to use the [`CONVERT_TZ`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) function to get your `my_timestamp_col` to UTC, and then call `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` on that:

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(timestamp, '-5:00', '+0:00'))
```

Another option would be to do this on the Java side, after all: get the field as a `Date`, which should do the timezone conversion for you; then call its `getTime()` method to get milliseconds since epoch, and subtract that from `System.currentTimeMillis()`. That gives you how many milliseconds ago the event happened.

Comment: Which will use the server time, not the client time. If his app really needs this subtle difference, he will have to do it client-side (i.e. javascript)

Comment: True; MySQL's handling of timezones is really messed up, which makes this a bit difficult (imho, the thing to do is not use the date/time types at all, but just store unix time seconds as an int). You can use the `CONVERT_TZ` method to convert the `my_timestamp_col` before you pass it to `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Really doing it in mysql would be fine for this never really looked into doing it that way.
Where would I use that UNIX_TIMESTAMP function to have 'timestamp' in seconds..... Currently it looks like...

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=gZ9LsM7z

Comment: You would replace `SELECT *` with `SELECT [fields you want]`, where `[fields you want]` is a comma-delimited list including the snippet above.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript's native Date object is able to replicate php's strtodate function very easily.
To call it, you would simply use:

```
var d = new Date(dateString);
```

(See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp for more information)
So you could use a function such as:

```
function timesince( dateString ) {
    var originalTime = new Date();          // The time you provided in milliseconds converted to javascript object
    var currentTime = new Date();                       // The current time as a javascript object
    return millisecondDifference = parseFloat(currentTime.getTime()) - parseFloat(originalTime.getTime());
    // returns the difference in milliseconds between the current time and the original time
    // parseFloat is used to ensure that the values returned are read by javascript as floats (numbers) and thus can have math operations performed on them
}
```

to return the difference in milliseconds. Then if you'd like to convert that to "Human Readable" format, you could use a new Date object as follows:

```
var diffRaw = timesince( '2014-03-19 12:00:43' );
var diff = new Date(diffRaw);
var seconds = diff.getSeconds() // Seconds from 0 - 59
var minutes = diff.getMinutes() // Minutes from 0 - 59
var hours = diff.getHours()     // Hours from 0 - 23
var day = diff.getDay()         // Days from 0 - 6
var date = diff.getDate()       // Date from 1 - 31
var month = diff.getMonth()     // Months from 0 - 11
var year = diff.getFullYear()   // XXXX year starting from 1970
```

To replicate the function you have written exactly, you could use the following function:

```
function timesince( dateString ) {
    var originalTime = new Date(dateString);
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var diffRaw = millisecondDifference = parseFloat(currentTime.getTime()) - parseFloat(originalTime.getTime());
    var diff = new Date(diffRaw);
    var seconds = diff.getSeconds();
    var minutes = diff.getMinutes();
    var hours = diff.getHours();
    var day = diff.getDay();
    var date = diff.getDate() - 1;
    var month = diff.getMonth();
    var year = diff.getFullYear();

    if( year !== 1970 ) {
        return "Not voted here yet.";
    }

    var returnString = "";
    if(month > 1 || month == 0) {
        returnString += month + " months, ";
    } else {
        returnString += month + " month, ";
    }

    if(date > 1 || date == 0) {
        returnString += date + " days, ";
    } else {
        returnString += date + " day, ";
    }

    if(hours > 1 || hours == 0) {
        returnString += hours + " hours, ";
    } else {
        returnString += hours + " hour, ";
    }

    if(minutes > 1 || minutes == 0) {
        returnString += minutes + " minutes, ";
    } else {
        returnString += minutes + " minute, ";
    }

    if(seconds > 1 || seconds == 0) {
        returnString += seconds + " seconds, ";
    } else {
        returnString += seconds + " second, ";
    }

    return returnString;
}
```

You can find a working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/MQPPw/

Comment: Thanks for that, though I really need it in Java, though I'm looking at just trying to get the seconds difference through mysql now

Comment: sorry it didn't help. i realize that you meant java not javascript only after i wrote the post. maybe something in the methodology might help though. good luck.